# Showing a progress dialog while doing multiple retrofit calls

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I want to do a list of calls to upload a list of pictures, show a progress dialog at the beginning and dismiss it at the end. Howewer the progress dialog never show up. If I comment progresRing.dismiss() then the dialog appear but later. Is there a better way to do multiple calls than in a for loop ?

```
        val progresRing = ProgressDialog(this@AddExtraPicturesActivity)
        progresRing.isIndeterminate = true
        progresRing.setTitle("Uploading pictures")
        progresRing.setMessage("Please wait")
        progresRing.setCancelable(false)

        progresRing.show()
        for (item in pictureList) {

            if(item.pictureFile != null) {
                val file = item.pictureFile

                if(file!!.exists()) {
                    var fileData = Base64.encodeToString(FileUtils.readFileToString(file).toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT)

                    val transactionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                    val tokenId = ""

                    val jobDocument = JobDocument("Test", "", "", "PHONE_PICTURE", "jpg", "test.jpg", "", fileData)
                    val requestBody = UploadDocumentRequest("Test", jobDocument)

                    val service = RestAPI(this@AddExtraPicturesActivity)


                    val request = service.uploadDocument(authorization, transactionId, tokenId, requestBody)

                    request.enqueue(object :  Callback<UploadDocumentResponse> {
                        override fun onResponse(call: Call<UploadDocumentResponse>, response: Response<UploadDocumentResponse>) {
                            Timber.d( response.toString())
                        }

                        override fun onFailure(call: Call<UploadDocumentResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                            Timber.d(t.toString())

                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        progresRing.dismiss()
```

Comment: Of course. You can use `Single.zip` from RxJava and start the loading in `doOnSubscribe`, and hide the loading dialog in `doFinally`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is definitely by using [Reactive Programming](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin) so you could have some sort of callback when all calls are done to perform another action.

An easier way would be to count the total number of calls you need to make and do the following:

```
// find here the total of calls you need to make before the loop
totalCount = ??
var = 0

// and later, as retrofit requests are asynchronous, on the last upload the condition will be valid and the progress should dismiss
request.enqueue(object :  Callback<UploadDocumentResponse> {
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<UploadDocumentResponse>, response: Response<UploadDocumentResponse>) {
                        Timber.d( response.toString())
                        var = var + 1
                        if(var == totalCount)
                            progresRing.dismiss()
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<UploadDocumentResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                        Timber.d(t.toString())

                    }
                })
```

Comment: I used the easier way because I couldn't really understand how to use reactive programming, I'll probably implement it later.